# How to run a shell script just by typing its name?

Tags: shell

I am very stuck on a task for my controlled assessment. I have been asked to create a shell script in nano that echoes hello world and hello $user. I have set the script to be executable. (chmod 755 Script1 and chmod +x Script1). I have been tasked to be able to make the script run just by typing 'Script1' , I do not know how to set the path to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set the PATH to include the directory is stored in. If it's in `/home/youruser/bin`, then run `PATH=$PATH:/home/youruser/bin`.

Comment: What you *should not* do is put `.` in the path -- that way lies security exploits. (Especially if it's at the front of the PATH; destructive files with names like `/tmp/ls` used to be common on multiuser systems to catch the unwary trying to run `ls` when in `/tmp`, but there's also a long history of attacks typosquatting on misspellings of common commands or correctly-spelled names of uninstalled programs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to have it in [the `PATH` environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).

Suppose it's in a folder on `/a/b/folder/script.sh`, try:

```
PATH=$PATH:/a/b/folder/
```

This tells the shell to look for executables there when looking for commands to run.

To make sure it's **always** executable you have several options:

1. Set the path variable in your profile using [`~/.bashrc`](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file) (sets it for `bash`, commonly done in `ubuntu`, which is what I use) or [`~/.profile`](http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/07/what-is-profile-file.html).
2. Set it globally using [`/etc/environment` or others](https://superuser.com/a/664236/164385)...
3. Move the folder to a folder already on your path (`echo $PATH` to see what's there already).

Note that these files are [`source`-ed on different stages and persist on different environments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables).

For even more information [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables).

**TIP:** To test that you've set the file correctly, we'll take `~/.bashrc` as an example, you can use `source ~/.bashrc` and everything in `~/.bashrc` will be loaded. That way you can be sure it won't mess things up next time you log in.

Comment: I have tried PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/Script1 , but it did not work. Im not really sure which path I am supposed to use but thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @JoelPodmore make sure you add the folder, not the file

Comment: @JoelPodmore, you should be putting **the directory storing the script** in the PATH, not **the script itself**. Which means you also probably shouldn't be putting scripts in your home directory to start with, since home directories tend to have all kinds of cruft in them.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it work. I typed  PATH=$PATH:/home/pi and it now works , thansk everyone

Comment: Does anyone know the simplest way to make it permenantly executable ?

Comment: The script is executable once you use `chmod u+x script` (set the executable bit for the user). If you mean how to make it available - that' what the answer is for.

Answer (score 0):

Alias the script in .bash_profile

in home path open the .bash_profile file and add the following entry,

alias Script1='/path/to/Script1'

Then reload the bash by,

. .bash_profile

After that try to call the script by using just its name. i.e, Script1